# Graduation and Job Search

Tags: job-search, united-states, hiring

I am currently a master's student in the US and I am in my final semester.

I have been a full-time student every semester and I have only a few weeks left in my program.

I am a US citizen, but I lived in both the US and my native country for roughly an equal number of years in each. Other than my higher education schooling in the US, I spent much of my adult life in my native country, so I don't know much about the job hunting process in the US.

In my native country, it is considered a socially embarrassing thing if one is neither a student nor a working professional (basically unemployed or not in education). Employers in my native country are hesitant to hire from this ambivalent group of people

**Is this sort of reasoning also common among American employers?**

I am concerned because I am in my last semester and I have so many academic tasks to complete. I don't have as much time as I would like to focus on job applications at the moment. Because of this, I don't know if I can have a job lined up by my graduation date.

Comment: Have you ever worked, or is this your first job?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  An American employer is unlikely to care that an applicant is an unemployed recent graduate rather than a current student.  At least for a reasonable period of time.  If it's been a couple years since graduation, though, that starts to wear thin.

That being said, however, I would encourage you to find the time to look for a job while you are still in school.  Applying for a job is generally easier when you're in school because employers come to recruit on campus.  That makes it much easier to get interviews.  It also brings employers to you rather than forcing you to spend time looking for employers over a wider geographic area and travelling to interviews. Many employers also have programs to hire new graduates that are timed to coincide with the academic calendar.  They expect to bring in a bunch of people in June/ July when large numbers of students graduate and to do do some sort of training/ orientation program for them before they start working.  Those opportunities may be closed if you wait until after graduation to start applying.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, no there is no such stigma in the US, although there is only a mild preference towards candidates that are either in school or currently employed.

Since you're still in school I highly recommend going to your school's placement office and start interviewing for jobs.  They normally welcome a bunch of larger companies that have needs to hire a certain number of candidates every year, so this is a very normal practice.  Being your last semester many of these companies may have already hired for their needs, but the only way to find out is to ask.

I can understand your time demands with trying to graduate, but you also need to address the importance of employment.

Good luck.

Agree with Justin's comment and +1.  (No clue why anyone would -1 it)